# Can't find out why the checkbox style is not applied

Tags: html, css, checkbox

[**I am trying to apply this CSS**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/miemhyjx) to my checkbox however it seems some other CSS is stopping it.

How can I identify what other CSS may be interfering with it or why its not applying that styling to my checkbox ?

[**Here is a live demo of my CSS and HTML**](http://cssdeck.com/labs/tfvfmpgg)

I have only applied it to the last set of checkboxes, I can see the `check` effect but the box itself does not show up and the old box even set to non still appears.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770615/how-to-use-firebug-to-easily-find-which-css-file-defines-a-particular-style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets overwritten because

```
#docContainer .fb-checkbox input
```

has more specificity than your style declaration of:

```
.regular-checkbox
```

change your style declaration to

```
#docContainer .fb-checkbox input.regular-checkbox
```

and it will have precedence over the previous style.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find out what's wrong with your code using firebug or the chrome developer tools for example. The reason your original checkbox doesn't get hidden is the `display: inline-block'` setting in the `#docContainer .fb-checkbox input` css on line 425.

Comment: I see, do you have any other helpful information as to why the style of the box is not showing ?

Comment: Try debugging it yourself, I've mentioned 2 possibilities to do so.

Comment: It gets overwritten because "#docContainer .fb-checkbox input" has more specificity than your ".regular-checkbox" style.  You can add "!important" to your ".regular-checkbox" style to make it hide.  For example:

.regular-checkbox { display: none !important; }

Although, "!important" is usually considered a last resort, and not recommended.  But your CSS is so gigantic, it's hard to parse through anyways.  This is the fastest/easiest fix I can think of.

Comment: @chadiusvt, I think it is a good idea to try to avoid the use of `!important` as much as possible. It can have annoying consequences later on and usually indicates your (css) structure could be improved.

Comment: @Patrick if I could I would have it done by now from the debugger it list everything as risked or not in use.

Comment: @Guapo, try minimizing your problem. Remove as much html and css code that is not related to this issue. It will make it easier to find out what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Guapo,  change ".regular-checkbox" to "#docContainer .fb-checkbox input.regular-checkbox" and it will have precedence over the other style.

Comment: @chadiusvt very appreciate for your input I have also removed that rule to see what happens with out much change, I will try the !important and see how it goes.

Comment: @chadiusvt your last comment works now I guess I just need to rework some other element to fix the size of it.

Comment: @chadiusvt thanks a lot found the last issue if you could make an answer with your reply I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your stylesheet and couldn't see that you have set the styling for the `input` checkboxes. I ran it through a fiddle and it works fine

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/eB4zz/

**Edited**

Your styles are being overwritten. I set `!important` next to each value for testing purposes and it then work fine.

[image]

Comment: yes it works if u don't use the rest of the CSS and HTML but doesn't mean much without the rest of the CSS and HTML ;).

Comment: Remove any other styling that refers to checkboxes. Also remove any generic input styling. Then one by one add these bits back until it breaks :)

Comment: Well I would like to fix it without having to use `!important`, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `display: none` gets overriden by other selectors (see Patrick's answer). In Firebug it's crossed out, meaning it has not been interpreted by your browser.

[Firebug http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/856/ldk8.png](http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/856/ldk8.png)

I recommend you to install Firebug for Firefox or use the developer tools provided by your browser. They will show you which styles are actually rendered by your browser.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
input[type="checkbox"] { 
    -moz-appearance: checkbox; -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
    margin-left:3px; border:0; 
    vertical-align: middle;    
    top: -1px;bottom: 1px;
    *overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */  
    *height: 13px; /* Removes excess padding in IE 7 */
    *width: 13px;
    backgorund: #ffffff; }
```